# Buildroot - missing i2c kernel modules

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel-modules, buildroot

I've used Buildroot to build a minimal operative system. During the configuration step with the `menuconfig` utility I specified to install I2C tools. The option was is

```
Target Package -> Hardware handling -> i2c-tools
```

But when I load the corresponding module I get the following error:

```
$sudo modprobe i2c-dev
modprobe: module i2c-dev not found in modules.dep
```

Furthermore, the list in the `modules.dep` file is empty.

```
$ cat /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/modules.dep
$
```

I have probably missed something important.

Do I have to manually copy the kernel modules from the Buildroot installation folder to the target system? How to make the i2c tools working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, `Target Package -> Hardware handling -> i2c-tools` refers to user space i2c utilities.

What you miss is kernel space i2c modules, you need to add them in `make linux-menuconfig`.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Mali, we need to enable the kernel support for SPI and I2C transmission protocol. I did it compiling the kernel separately but we can do it from the Buildroot folder runnning `make linux-menuconfig`

During the kernel 3.8.13 configuration, add:

```
linux-3.8.13$ make menuconfig
```

- Go to **Device Drivers** menu and check the **I2C support** pressing ‘Y’.
- Enter the I2C menu, go to **I2C device interface** and Press ‘**M**’ for module support.
- Enter the **I2C Hardware Bus support** menu and press ‘M’ **BCM2708 BSC**
- Check the **SPI support** pressing ‘Y’ and enter the sub menu
- Press ‘M’ near the **BCM2708 SPI controller driver**

Cross compile it and once done you can load the modules with

```
modprobe i2c-dev
modprobe i2c-bcm2708
modprobe spi-bcm2708
```